# Why won't gridlines show up in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

```
if zeta < 1
omegad = omegan*sqrt(1-zeta^2);
c1 = y0;
c2 = ydot0/(omegan);
p1 = (-zeta*omegan)+(omegan)*sqrt((zeta^2)-1);
p2 = (-zeta*omegan)-(omegan)*sqrt((zeta^2)-1);

x = c1*exp(p1*t)+c2*exp(p2*t);
xdot = p1*c1*exp(p1*t)+p2*c2*exp(p2*t);
set(handles.omegad_output,'String',omegad);

elseif zeta == 1
omegad = omegan*sqrt(1-zeta^2);
c1 = y0;
c2 = ydot0/(omegan);
x = c1*exp(-omegan.*t)+c2.*t*exp(-omegan.*t);
xdot = -omegan*c1*exp(-omegan.*t)-omegan*c2*t*exp(-omegan*t)+t*exp(-omegan*t);
set(handles.omegad_output,'String',omegad);

else 
omegad = omegan*sqrt(1-zeta^2);
c1 = y0;
c2 = (ydot0+zeta*omegan*y0)/omegad; 
x = exp(-zeta*omegan.*t).*(c1*cos(omegad.*t)+c2*sin(omegad.*t));
A = -zeta*omegan*exp(-zeta*omegan.*t);
B = c1*cos(omegad.*t)+c2*sin(omegad.*t);
C = exp(-zeta*omegan.*t);
D = -c1*omegad*sin(omegad.*t)+c2*omegad*cos(omegad.*t);
xdot = A.*B+C.*D;
set(handles.omegad_output,'String',omegad);
end



% Create Amplitude plot in proper axes
plot(handles.amplitude_axes,t,x)
set(handles.amplitude_axes,'XMinorTick','on')
grid on

% Create Velocity plot in proper axes
plot(handles.velocity_axes,t,xdot)
set(handles.velocity_axes,'XMinorTick','on')
grid on
```

Im constructing a GUI and here is the plot button callback function. I have the above code and when I plot it the gridlines only come up for the Amplitude plot and not the Velocity plot, how do I have the gridlines show up for both plots.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `grid on` with:

```
grid (handles.velocity_axes,'on')
grid (handles.amplitude_axes,'on')
```

This is because the command form of `grid` works only on the current axes `gca`. Plotting in specific axes won't make those axes current, thus the second `grid on` will apply again on the current axes, which happens to be the Amplitude plot.

Comment: Thanks so much that fixed it!